# php file permissions, unable to copy: failed to open stream

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I have a fresh Apache/PHP webserver running on Ubuntu server. My PHP isn't able to copy/rename files. I have a file with 777 and even owner is www-data.

```
Warning: rename(/tmp/test.jpg,/var/www/test.jpg): No such file or directory in /var/www/info.php
Warning: copy(/var/www/test.jpg,/var/www/new-folder/test.jpg): No such file or directory in /var/www/info.php
```

Webserver:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 12 2013 13:37:10
```

PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8 with Suhosin-Patch.

Comment: You encountered a path problem, not a permission problem. Read the error message carefully

Comment: the file may be 777, but what about the directories you're copying from/to?

Comment: @hek2mgl , I have no idea, I use '/tmp/test.jpg', this should be a full path? do you have anything in mind ?

Comment: No such file or directory :/

Comment: @MarcB, I'm getting 'failed to open stream', It's not reading the file...

Comment: Having just the information you gave us, I'm with @SamyMassoud

Comment: @amin: yes, and? If I put an envelope marked "For Amin" in a bank vault, you're totally 100% able to read the contents of the envelope, just as soon as you dynamite open the vault door...

Comment: i wonder is /tmp folder inside your app ?

Comment: @SamyMassoud, no no it's not, it's the systems temp directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that this file is exist

```
/tmp/test.jpg
```

And really you should know that /tmp 
may refer to system tmp folder so it will give you this issue ,
so for a quick fix you should specify full link to your /tmp inside your app
using `__DIR__` or any path related keyword

Comment: Thank you, I finally got it to work, it seems that my project was actually reading wrong file extension. the file was there, but the wrong extension
jpg, png, gif...etc

Answer (score 3):

use php comand `echo realpath(dirname(__FILE__));` to understand your full path structure. then adapt it to your file path.

maybe `/tmp/` and `/var/www/` are wrong. with the above comand you should be able to see the full path to your www folder.

Comment: Thank you, I finally got it to work, it seems that my project was actually reading wrong file extension. the file was there, but the wrong extension
jpg, png, gif...etc